# Erlang basic recursion with guards

Tags: erlang

I am trying to create a very simple recursive function to delete all element that have a particular value that the user decides on from a list.

In haskell I would use guards and do:

```
deleteAll_rec _ [] = []
deleteAll_rec del (x:xs) | del==x = deleteAll_rec del xs
                         | otherwise = x:deleteAll_rec del xs
```

I am trying to code up an Erlang equivalent, however, I am not sure how to handle the `otherwise` case:

```
deleteAll_rec(_, []) -> [];
deleteAll_rec(DEL, [X|XS]) when DEL =:= X -> deleteAll_rec(DEL, XS).
```

I was wondering if someone can demonstrate how this can be done?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *otherwise* becomes a separate clause in Erlang:

```
delete_all_rec(_, []) -> [];
delete_all_rec(Del, [Del|Xs]) ->
    delete_all_rec(Del, Xs);
delete_all_rec(Del, [X|Xs]) ->
    [X|delete_all_rec(Del, Xs)].
```

An alternative is to use an `if` like:

```
delete_all_rec(_, []) -> [];
delete_all_rec(Del, [X|Xs]) ->
    if Del =:= X ->
            delete_all_rec(Del, Xs);
        true ->
            [X|delete_all_rec(Del, Xs)]
    end.
```

The resultant code is the same but I think the first version looks better. Whether you put the terminating case first or last is irrelevant in this example, I prefer putting it last.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How are we checking if DEL equals the Head of the list? in the middle clause of the first implementation?

Comment: Yes this `delete_all_rec(Del, [Del|Xs])` matches when Del is the first argument of the function and the list's head.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Sorry for not mentioning this. When a variable occurs more than once in a pattern or head there is an implicit equality check. In this case the first argument `Del` is equal to the first element `Del` of the list. IIRC in Haskell you always have to explicitly test for equality.