# Understanding Erlang Basic recursion with function guards

Tags: recursion, erlang

I've been looking at some Erlang recursion examples asked earlier here on stackoverflow.

Specifically with this question [Erlang basic recursion with guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046586/erlang-basic-recursion-with-guards?rq=1)

But I can't quite understand how the code works. So I have created a module to see the results it returns with a simple list with 3 elements.

```
-module(recursion). 
-export([start/0]). 


start() -> 
    List = [1,2,3],
    Final = delete(1,List),
    Final.
   

delete(_, []) -> 
    io:format("return []~n~n~n"),
    [];
delete(Del, [Del|Xs]) ->
    io:format("~p =:= ~p~n",[Del,Del]),
    io:format("delete(~p, ~p)~n~n~n~n",[Del,Xs]),
    delete(Del, Xs);
delete(Del, [X|Xs]) ->
    io:format("~p =/= ~p~n",[Del,X]),
    io:format(" [~p|delete(~p, ~p)]~n~n~n~n",[X,Del,Xs]),
    [X|delete(Del, Xs)].
```

And this is the result of the log

```
1> recursion:start().
1 =:= 1
delete(1, [2,3])



1 =/= 2
 [2|delete(1, [3])]                



1 =/= 3
 [3|delete(1, [])]               


return []    The result of the 'Final' variable of the main function, shouldn't it be []?
             bacause [3|delete(3, [])] in the last call matches with delete(_, []) -> []
             
             or is it this way?  [2,[3,[]]] -> [2,3]


[2,3]
2>
```

My question is:
Every time the program calls **delete(Del, [X|Xs]) ->**, is the function returning the value to the previous call?
Is it being stored somewhere?
or is it just something like that? **[2,[3,[]]] -> [2,3]**

edit:
I think I have found the solution in this link,  about how the final result is built
https://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists
where

```
13> List = [2,3,4].
[2,3,4]
14> NewList = [1|List].
[1,2,3,4]
```

So [2|[3|[]]] -> [2,3]

is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

This is how the function works:

1. If the head of the list matches the first argument, `1` in this case, then the head of the list isn't saved anywhere, i.e. it's skipped, and the function is called again with the tail of the list:

   ```
    delete(Del, [Del|Xs]) ->
        delete(Del, Xs);
   ```
2. If the head of the list does NOT match the first argument, then the head of the list is saved by adding it to a result list:

   ```
   [X|delete(Del, Xs)].
   ```
3. When the list is empty, the function returns `[]`, which is very important when cons'ing elements together:

   ```
    [3 | f(X) ]
   ```

if f(X) does not return a list at some point, then the list won't be a `proper` list.  A proper list, such as:

```
    [1, 2, 3]
```

is equivalent to:

```
    [1 | [2 | [3 | [] ]]]
```

as you can see here:

```
    2> [1 | [2 | [3 | [] ]]].
    [1,2,3]
```

When you write:

```
[X|delete(Del, Xs)]
```

that's a little be tricky, and you need some experience to know how that works.   You can understand things better, by writing out by hand what is happening:

```
delete(1, [1,2,3])
        |
        V
   delete(1, [2, 3])
           |
           V
      [2 | delete(1, [3]) ]  %% Can't know the result here without determining the return value of delete(1, [3])
                    |
                    V
                [3 | delete(1, []) ]  %% Can't know the result here without determining the return value of delete(1, [])
                          |
                          V
                          []
```

Once, you've got the return value `[]`, because there are no more function calls in the result, now you can move upwards substituting:

```
delete(1, [1,2,3])
        |
        V
   delete(1, [2, 3])
           |
           V
      [2 | delete(1, [3]) ]
                    |
                    V
                [3 | [] ]
```

And substituting again:

```
delete(1, [1,2,3])
        |
        V
   delete(1, [2, 3])
           |
           V
      [2 | [3 | [] ] ]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[2, 3]
```

Here is a conceptually simpler version of `delete()`:

```
start() -> 
    List = [1,2,3],
    Final = delete(1,List),
    Final.
   

delete(Term, List) ->
    delete(Term, List, _Acc=[]).

delete(_, [], Acc) -> 
    Acc;
delete(Term, [Term|Xs], Acc) ->
    delete(Term, Xs, Acc);
delete(Term, [X|Xs], Acc) ->
    delete(Term, Xs, [X|Acc]).
```

However, the result is:

```
 [3, 2]
```

So, when you use an *accumulator* variable, you need to reverse the final result:

```
delete(_, [], Acc) -> 
    lists:reverse(Acc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Dac2020, I added some more.

Comment: Yes, it is easier to understand. But I just have a question. In this line: delete(Term, List, _Acc=[]).  _Acc=[] means passing an empty list to delete/3 ?

Comment: I think so because I have changed the line for this delete (Term, List, []). and works. I mean, I guess it's just to clarify

Comment: Related article I wrote a while back: https://medium.com/erlang-battleground/how-to-comprehend-comprehensions-c924f92a97e1

Comment: @Dac2020, *_Acc=[] means passing an empty list to delete/3*.  Yes, calling `delete(Term, List, _Acc = [])` is equivalent to calling `delete(Term, List, [])`.  Adding the variable name `_Acc` is an attempt to make it clear what the empty list represents.